# How to build a vector one element by one element?

Tags: arrays, matlab

In Matlab, I need to build a vector with the first 20 Fibonacci numbers. I have a function which returns them. How can I add every element my function returns one by one into my vector?

Comment: What are the inputs and  outputs to the function you mentioned which returns Fibonacci numbers?  Did you write this function yourself?  If so, can we see the code?

Comment: thanks for your help!! The answer of POW already solved it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some `fibonacci` function

Then can do something like this :-

```
N = 20; %// Total count

vect= zeros(1,N);
vect(1) = 1;
for k = 2:N
    vect(k) = fibonacci(k-1); % Your fibonacci function
end
```

Comment: Of course, this approach is horrible.  It would be much better to use the stored values to calculate the next value instantly, instead of using recursion.  (Not sure if the OP is allowed to do this, however)

Comment: @BenVoigt Okay removed, wasn't asked in post the` fibonacci generator implementation. Yeah it was indeed horrible.